You're importing a component that needs "next/headers". That only works in a Server Component which is not supported in the pages/ directory
I have a client component that renders a signup form in Next.js 15.0.1 using Material UI for the frontend library. I'm also using react-hook-form (and react 18.3.1). When I try to load the signup page, I get the error in the title. I'm using the app router, so, there is no pages directory. And I'm using supabase as the backend database and for user authentication (with bcrypt on the frontend for password hashing). Also, I'd like to avoid using the supabase client-side client and do authentication strictly on the server.
I'm not sure what's wrong...here's the relevant code...does anyone know how to solve this?
// app/(public)/signup/page.tsx

'use client';

import { Typography, Stack } from '@mui/material';
import LifestyleContainer from '@/components/groupings/LifestyleContainer';
import SignupForm from '@/app/(public)/signup/form';

const SignupPage: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {

  return (
    <Stack sx={{ gap: '50px', mb: 12 }}>
      <LifestyleContainer>
        <Typography variant='h4'>
          Sign Up
        </Typography>
      </LifestyleContainer>
      <LifestyleContainer>
        <SignupForm />
      </LifestyleContainer>
    </Stack>
  );
};
 
export default SignupPage;


// app/(public)/signup/form.tsx

import { createSupabaseClient } from '@/utils/supabase/server';
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid2'
import LifestyleFormButton from '@/components/buttons/LifestyleFormButton';
import { countries, us_states } from '@/data/geography/geographics';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useForm, SubmitHandler, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import Form from 'next/Form';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  FormControl, Stack, Typography,
  MenuItem, TextField, Select
} from '@mui/material';


const StyledForm = styled(Form)`
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 50px;
  border-radius: 20px;
`;

const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)`
  .MuiInputBase-root {
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 12px;
  }
  
  .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
    border-radius: 12px;
  }
`;

const StyledSelectInput = styled(Select)`
  border-radius: 12px;
  height: 32px;
`;

type Inputs = {
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  country: string;
  state: string;
  street_address: string;
  city: string;
  zip_code: string;
  phone: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

const SignupForm: React.FC = async(): Promise<JSX.Element> => {
  const supabase = await createSupabaseClient();

  const { control, handleSubmit, reset, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm<Inputs>();

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Inputs> = async (data) => {
    try {
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(data.password, 10);
      const payload = { ...data, password: hashedPassword };

      const response = await axios.post('/api/signup', payload);
      const result = response.data;

      if (!result.user) {
        console.error('Error:', result.error);
        return
      }

      console.log('User signed up successfully:', result.user);
      reset();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Unexpected error:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <StyledForm action='/' onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Stack sx={{ gap: '20px' }}>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid size={{ xs: 6 }}>
            <FormControl fullWidth>
              <Controller
                name='first_name'
                control={control}
                defaultValue=''
                render={({ field }) =>
                  <StyledTextField placeholder='first name' {...field} required />
                }
              />
            </FormControl>
          </Grid>
          <Grid size={{ xs: 6 }}>
            <FormControl fullWidth>
              <Controller
                name='last_name'
                control={control}
                defaultValue=''
                render={({ field }) =>
                  <StyledTextField placeholder='last name' {...field} required />
                }
              />
            </FormControl>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid size={{ xs: 6 }}>
            <FormControl fullWidth>
              <Controller
                name='country'
                control={control}
                defaultValue='select country'
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <StyledSelectInput 
                    {...field}
                    displayEmpty
                  >
                    <MenuItem value='select country' disabled>
                      <Typography sx={{ fontSize: '0.9rem', color: '#a6a6a6' }}>
                        select country
                      </Typography>
                    </MenuItem>
                    {countries.map(country => (
                      <MenuItem key={country.Code} value={country.Name}>
                        { country.Name }
                      </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                  </StyledSelectInput>
                )}
              />
            </FormControl>
          </Grid>
          <Grid size={{ xs: 6 }}>
            <FormControl disabled={watch('country') !== 'United States'} fullWidth>
              <Controller
                name='state'
                defaultValue='select state (U.S. only)'
                control={control}
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <StyledSelectInput 
                    {...field}
                    sx={{ backgroundColor: watch('country') !== 'United States' ? '#d4d4d4' : '' }}
                  >
                    <MenuItem value='select state (U.S. only)' disabled>
                      <Typography sx={{ fontSize: '0.9rem', color: '#a6a6a6' }}>
                        select state - U.S. only
                      </Typography>
                    </MenuItem>
                    {us_states.map(state => (
                      <MenuItem key={state.Name} value={state.Name}>
                        { state.Name }
                      </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                  </StyledSelectInput>
                )}
              />
            </FormControl>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid size={{ xs: 6 }}>
            <FormControl fullWidth>
              <Controller
                name='street_address'
                defaultValue=''
                control={control}
                render={({ field }) =>
                  <StyledTextField 
                    placeholder='street address' 
                    {...field} 
                    required 
                  />
                }
              />
            </FormControl>
          </Grid>
          <Grid size={{ xs: 6 }}>
            <FormControl fullWidth>
              <Controller
                name='city'
                defaultValue=''
                control={control}
                render={({ field }) =>
                  <StyledTextField 
                    placeholder='city'
                    {...field} 
                    required 
                  />
                }
              />
            </FormControl>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid size={{ xs: 6 }}>
            <FormControl fullWidth>
              <Controller
                name='zip_code'
                defaultValue=''
                control={control}
                render={({ field }) =>
                  <StyledTextField 
                    placeholder='zip code (or "no zip")' 
                    {...field} 
                    required 
                  />
                }
              />
            </FormControl>
          </Grid>
          <Grid size={{ xs: 6 }}>
            <FormControl fullWidth>
              <Controller
                name='phone'
                defaultValue=''
                control={control}
                render={({ field }) =>
                  <StyledTextField 
                    placeholder='phone (e.g., +001-000...)' 
                    {...field} 
                    required 
                  />
                }
              />
            </FormControl>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <FormControl>
          <Controller
            name='email'
            defaultValue=''
            control={control}
            render={({ field }) =>
              <StyledTextField 
                type='email' 
                placeholder='email' 
                {...field} 
                required 
              />
            }
          />
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl>
          <Controller
            name='password'
            defaultValue=''
            control={control}
            render={({ field }) =>
              <StyledTextField 
                type='password' 
                slotProps={{
                  htmlInput: {
                    minLength: 10
                  }
                }}
                placeholder='password' 
                {...field} 
                required 
              />
            }
          />
        </FormControl>
        <LifestyleFormButton>
          SIGNUP
        </LifestyleFormButton>
        <Stack
          direction='row'
          sx={{
            gap: '20px',
            alignItems: 'center'
          }}
        >
          <Typography>
            Already have an account?
          </Typography>
          <Link 
            href='/login' 
            style={{ 
              color: 'blue', 
              textDecoration: 'none' 
            }}
          >
            login
          </Link>
        </Stack>
      </Stack>
    </StyledForm>
  );
};

export default SignupForm;

// src/utils/supabase/server.ts

import { createServerClient, type CookieOptions } from '@supabase/ssr'
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'

export const createSupabaseClient = async() => {
  const cookieStore = await cookies();

  return createServerClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!,
    {
      cookies: {
        getAll() {
          return cookieStore.getAll()
        },
        setAll(cookiesToSet) {
          try {
            cookiesToSet.forEach(({ name, value, options }) =>
              cookieStore.set(name, value, options)
            )
          } catch {
            // The `setAll` method was called from a Server Component.
            // This can be ignored if you have middleware refreshing
            // user sessions.
          }
        },
      },
    }
  );
};

// app/api/signup/route.ts

import { createSupabaseClient } from '@/utils/supabase/server';
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export const POST = async(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) => {
  const supabase = await createSupabaseClient();
  console.log(supabase);
  const { email, password, ...profileData } = await req.json();

  try {
    const { data: { user }, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({ email, password });

    if (error) return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message }, { status: 400 });    

    const { error: profileError } = await supabase
      .from('user_profiles')
      .insert([{ id: user?.id, ...profileData }]);

      if (profileError) return NextResponse.json({ error: profileError.message }, { status: 400 });
      
      return NextResponse.json({ user }, { status: 200 });
    } catch (error) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Unexpected error' }, { status: 500 });
    }
};



Stupid mistake...had a stray createSupabaseClient() in the form.tsx component, when it only belonged in the api route. Deleted from form.tsx, and everything is working.
